# Почему происходит ошибка приложения?

Tags: c++

Я недавно стал изучать C++ и привык что C++ сам заботится о приведении типов/вычислениях/памяти и неожидал что в нижеследующем коде будет ошибка причём не при компиляции а во время выполнения!
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
const int minutes_in_degree = 60; // минут в градусе
int seconds_in_minute = 60; // секунд в минуте
int degrees = 0; // градусы
int minutes = 0; // минуты
int seconds = 0; // секунды
double totalDegrees = 0; // всего градусов
int main(void){
   using namespace std;
   cout << "Enter a latitude in degrees, minutes and seconds:" << endl;
   cout << "First, enter the degrees: ";
   cin >> degrees;
   cout << "Next, enter the minutes of arc: ";
   cin >> minutes;
   cout << "Finally, enter the seconds of arc: ";
   cin >> seconds;
   //Ошибка в выражении ниже
   totalDegrees = minutes_in_degree / minutes +
   minutes_in_degree / (seconds / seconds_in_minute) + degrees;
   // код ниже уже не работает из-за ошибки выше
   cout << degrees << " degrees, " << minutes << " minutes, " << seconds
   << " seconds = " << totalDegrees << " degrees" << endl;
   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Я сначала хотел вывести результаты на прямую (написать выражения прямо после `<<`) произошла ошибка решил что памяти не хватает или чтото типа того и создал переменную и присвоил ей значение (как в коде выше) но опять была ошибка Потом каждый кусок между `+` прибывлял отдельно и узнал что ошибка собственно в выражении: `seconds / seconds_in_minute` а если написать:

```
cout <<  (seconds / seconds_in_minute);
```

то почему-то сначала выводится `0` а потом программа на 1 секунду зависает и выводит символ как будто запрашивает ввод данных а потом Windows предлагает "Закрыть неработающюю программу"
Почему так происходит?
P.S: Если это важно у меня Windows 7 Максимальная и IDE Dev C++ , о компиляторах:
[image: ScreenShoot окна "О компиляторах" Dev C++]
P.P.S: Я ввожу 37 51 19 и в книге написано что должно почучиться 37,8553 а у меня ошибка :(
В книге нет решения просто задание данные для ввода и результат, а задание такое:

> Напишите программу, которая выдавала
> бы запрос на ввод широты в rpaдycax, 
> минутах и секундах, после чего
> отображала бы широту в десятичном
> формате.  В одной минуте 60 секунд, а
> в одном rpaдyce 60 минут; представьте
> эти значения посредством
> символьных констант. Для каждого
> вводимого значения следует
> использовать отдельную переменную.

Comment: `gdb` записали в компиляторы, пичалько...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я щас наверное скажу какую-нить глупость... А почему вы делите `minutes_in_degree/minutes` и `minutes_in_degree/(seconds / seconds_in_minute)`?

```
totalDegrees = degrees + (minutes + seconds/seconds_in_minute)/minutes_in_degree;
```

ЗЫ [запускающийся пример](http://ideone.com/DZT8b).

Comment: Спасибо @Yura Ivanov !

Comment: Только вот почему значение degrees из 37 превращяется в чёто странное как это исправить :( ?

Comment: Из-за этого?

    cout <<  (seconds / seconds_in_minute);

Видимо для отладки у вас было...

Comment: где это я не вижу? 

      сout << degrees << " degrees, " << minutes << " minutes, " << seconds
      << " seconds = " << totalDegrees << " degrees" << endl;

сдксь degrees почемуто портится

Comment: А, вы всё уже исправили понятно! Спасибо ещё раз извините за путаницу :)

Comment: Примерно вот тут:

    cout << "Finally, enter the seconds of arc: ";
    cin >> seconds;
    cout <<  (seconds / seconds_in_minute);

Comment: да ничего. бывает. удачи!

Answer (score 5):

У Вас деление на 0 (по крайней мере в `minutes_in_degree / (seconds / seconds_in_minute)` так как `seconds / seconds_in_minute` даст 0 из-за типа `int`).

Вместо `int degrees, minutes, seconds` используйте `double`.

Comment: Если стремиться сделать правильно, то достаточно привести rvalue к действительному типу.

Comment: А как "привести к действительному типу"?

Comment: Я исправил на minutes_in_degree / minutes +
   minutes_in_degree / double(seconds / seconds_in_minute) + degrees но теперь при вводе 37 51 19 получается 1.#INF degrees помогите как правильно написать

Comment: @Rules, я объяснил почему програма **падает**. Проверки делений на ноль и разработки **правильного алгоритма** это не отменяет.

Очевидно, если seconds ноль, то их просто не надо считать. Например

    totalDegrees = minutes_in_degree / minutes +
   minutes_in_degree / (seconds / seconds_in_minute) + degrees;

можно скорректоровать:

    totalDegrees = minutes > 0 ? minutes_in_degree / minutes : 0 + seconds > 0 ?
   minutes_in_degree / (seconds / seconds_in_minute) : 0 + degrees;

Comment: Прочел (наконец-то !) условие задачи. IMHO 

    double totalDegrees = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600;

И проверять ничего не надо.

С другой стороны, для обучения хорошая ошибка. Теперь ТС знает о результатах деления на 0 и сопутствующих этому процедурах разработки.

Comment: Да спасибо а в книжке ничего об этом ктомуже раньше юзал JS с NAN и неожидал такой ошибки :) Спасибо за урок (который должен был дать автор книги но не выполнил свой долг:) )

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, выражение неверно. Как его исправить уже подсказали, но есть одна ошибка. Числа имеют тип int, поэтому при делении получатся тоже целые числа, округлённые вниз. Поэтому надо преобразовать хотя бы один из операндов всех операторов к вещественному числу. Вот исправленный код:

```
totalDegrees=((double)seconds/seconds_in_minute+minutes)/minutes_in_degree+degrees;
```

Во-вторых, судя по всему, автор упражнения требовал использовать символьные константы. minutes_in_degree объявлена правильно, но seconds_in_minute - не константа, а переменная.

В-третьих, замечание по стилю программирования. Не надо использовать глобальные переменные. Минуты, секунды и градусы вполне можно было бы объявить внутри функции main. Да и константы эти тоже можно туда перенести.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, вместо

```
totalDegrees = minutes_in_degree / minutes +
    minutes_in_degree / (seconds / seconds_in_minute) + degrees;
```

должно быть

```
totalDegrees = (seconds / seconds_in_minute + minutes) /
    minutes_in_degree + degrees;
```